# (UPDATE: Yes or cunningham's law) Joke answers allowed? Seriously?

Tags: discussion, answers

> No, what you did is what is known as a [gambit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambit). You offered your opponent material (in this case a water bottle), which he accepted. This would be considered a blunder on his part, since although it gave him a temporary hydration advantage, it ended up costing him time due to uncomfortable situation it caused for his bladder, which needed to be resolved. If he had instead declined the gambit, me may have won, but such is the way of the game.

https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/33544

I have tried posting joke answers, but I believe still technically correct answers under the joke, on other se sites, and they have been removed.

Back to this site:

Already flagged the above answer. I did not get even a disputed. I really got a declined. Okay, I'm not saying I'm right or anything. I really want to understand? Seriously? what's up with this?

Note 1:

I think (joke chess)-(answers) are or should be allowed (https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/24423), but really (joke)-(chess answers)? come on.

Note 2:

If downvoting a meta question means a negative answer, then...

Note 3:

Re the answer, why can't we just that joke comments are allowed but joke answers are not? see my [folklore question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/116019/inadmissible-theorems-in-research/116035#comment305274_116019) which has 'I would have said by virtue of being hospitalized, L'Hopital's rule should be fair game. ' i think it is ok as comment but not ok as an answer. but like ok with me i guess. i'll post a bunch of joke answers i guess. i just thought it was perhaps an oversight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joke answers like this are ok.

If the OP for the aforementioned link or someone else gets in trouble for offering such gambits, then well...

(alternatively this post is an application of cunningham's law)

Answer (score 8):

I agree. Chess is a serious game and there should be no tolerance for any fun or jokes. All puns should be punished. All innuendo ended. Cunning linguists should have their tongues cut out. Only once we have banished all laughter can we become grandmasters.

Comment: pkr -_-..................

Comment: well i just figured it could be given as a comment instead of an answer

Comment: ok i will post an answer saying it is ok. cunningham's law

Comment: in your opinion why can't we just that joke comments are allowed but joke answers are not? see my folklore question which has 'I would have said by virtue of being hospitalized, L'Hopital's rule should be fair game. ' https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/116019/inadmissible-theorems-in-research/116035#comment305274_116019 i think it is ok as comment but not ok as an answer. but like ok with me i guess. i'll post a bunch of joke answers i guess. i just thought it was perhaps an oversight.

Comment: Ah, but the problem here is rather Poe's Law. Even if the joke is outrageous, some simply won't get it. I'm taking bets pkr's answer above falls under it. Thus, whereas I might put in puns, popcultural snippets and anecdotes into my answers, I'd avoid outright joking.

Comment: Poe's law vs cunningham's law. interesting.........post as answer?

Comment: @HaukeReddmann oh i forgot to tag you